# printing 2d array with conditions

Tags: java

I have one method that should write 2D int array like matrix and add ? on specific place (you get dimensions of that place as parameter).

Yes, I wrote int because in case of value of 0 I Should write A, in case of value 1 B and so on...

Example:

```
A  B  C
B  A? A
```

Between them should be \t but not before first element in row and after last element.
What is easiest way to this? I know I can get this if write multiple If...if else conditions but would like to know if there is any shorter code for that.

Comment: what is your approcah and share your effort to help you further.

Comment: There is no code but I shared my effort telling how I did it, but it is way too long. Sorry I can not put the code because my uni doesnt allow sharing it @ShankarSaranSingh

Comment: Theoroically and programmatically understanding are two different thngs, stackoverflow is to help but not to write whole code and share, if you share your efforts community can help you in learning the cause and fix in your approach, hope you undesand.

Comment: Yes, but rules of my university are more important to me. I didnt asked to write whole code it was more about giving tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a 2D array and you are given some int values that should be replaced by characters when printing.

One of the solutions you can do is to create another function with switch case like this:

```
       private String charOf(int x, int colIndex, int maxCols){
            Char char = '';
            switch(int){
                     case 1: 
                             char = 'A';
                             break;
                     case 2:
                             char = 'B';
                             break;
                     ....... etc
             }
          return (colIndex < maxCols-1 ? char+"\t" : char);
       }
```

Then call this function upon printing:

```
        print (charOf(arr[i][j]);
```

As for the question mark, I think one if statement inside the inner loop can do this, or in one line you can use this:

```
        ((i==x && j==y) ?  print(charOf(arr[i][j])+"?"): print(charOf(arr[i][j]))
```

Assuming that x and y are the two parameters you function takes to specify which element to print a question mark beside.

Comment: I edited my answer to return the tab also, assuming you will pass to the switch case function the index of the column and max number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

after initialize your array 
for example

```
int[][] array = new int[2][3];
     array[0][0] = 1;
     array[0][1] = 2;
     array[0][2] = 3;
     array[1][0] = 1;
     array[1][1] = 4;
     array[1][2] = 5;
```

you can use ASCII code

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
         int myasci = 65 + array[i][j];
         String MyChar = (char) myasci+"";
         if(/* Your ? conditon */){
            MyChar = MyChar+"?";
         }
         System.out.print(MyChar+'\t');
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

The ASCII code of capital letters starts from 65 For 'A' 66 For 'B' 
so you can add the value of your int to 65 to get the Ascii code for number for example when the int is 0 it will be 65 + 0 = 65 and this is 'A' ASCII code

Comment: But you will have tab after last element in row and I should not :)